# Custom database for Forms based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, forms-authentication, fba

I'm a bit new to Asp.Net forms authentication, but I have gotten a good grip of it.  I'm currently stuck with a problem.  I want to store user credentials in a table under my custom database.  By default, Visual Studio creates a mdf file, is there any way to override this behaviour?

With the User credentials table in my Sql Server Database, I will have better control over the content of my site and will be more organized.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should create a custom Membership Provider. You able to customize how to store user credentials to database.

Here sample link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers